# List, Group multiple instances of an object based on ManyToMany field in Django

Tags: django, orm, group-by, many-to-many

Given the following models, I need to return a list of **Links** for each **Place**, grouped by **Category**.

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

class Link(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()
    place = models.ManyToManyField('Place')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
    description = models.TextField()
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    published = models.BooleanField()
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The result would look something like:

**Some Place**

Information about Some Place ... (not really important to question)

**Banks**

Bank of America

Commerce Bank

First National Bank

**Financial Services**

Bank of America

Edward Jones

**Loans**

Commerce Bank

First National Bank

As you can see, a **Link** should be listed in every **Category** in which it belongs.

I tried to loop through categories and concatenate the querysets, but with ManyToMany fields, it doesn't seem possible to do the sort necessary that can be passed into the template and grouped there.

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem? I tried this myself on the console, here is the traceback, that should help you.

```
 >>> ny = Place.objects.create(name='NewYork')
 >>> bank = Category.objects.create(name='bank',description='aaa')
 >>> bofa = Link.objects.create(name='BofA',url='http://google.com',description='a')
 >>> bofa.place.add(ny)
 >>> bofa.categories.add(bank)
 >>> ny.link_set.all()
 [Link: Link object]    # This is `bofa`
 >>> ny.link_set.filter(categories=bank)
 [Link: Link object]
 >>>
```

Where is the problem? To display all the links category wise, of a particular place,

- Get the place object Use `get_object_or_404`. `ny` in the example above
- Obtain all links in the place, filter for the category you need. (You may need to obtain list of all categories in this place, similarly.)

Comment: If you just do place.link_set.all() like that, links that are supposed to appear in multiple categories only show in the queryset once instead of once for each category in which they are listed. Not to mention there is no way to sort links by category name. I think the way to do this is to use an intermediary field for the ManyToMany relationships. That way the instances of each listing in each category can be retrieved and sorted.